# Create trailing effect on a Sprite with Pixi.js (V4)

Tags: typescript, sprite, pixi.js

I have this method that moves a Sprite horizontally, which works fine, but I am really puzzled in how to add a trailing effect to it. I want to leave in the canvas a print of the sprite while is moving.

here is my current code (I am using TypeScript)

```
    private dash = () => {
    let warriorLeftPosX = this.viking.x + this.viking.width;
    let warriorRightPosX = this.mountainMan.x - this.mountainMan.width;
    this.viking.vx = this.vikingProperties.sprite_loop_velocity;
    this.mountainMan.vx = this.mountainManProperties.sprite_loop_velocity;
    this.viking.accelerationX = this.vikingProperties.animation.dash.acceleration;
    this.mountainMan.accelerationX = this.mountainManProperties.animation.dash.acceleration;

    if (warriorRightPosX > this.renderer.view.width / 2 - (this.mountainMan.width / 6)
        || warriorLeftPosX < this.renderer.view.width / 2 - (this.viking.width / 6)) {

        this.mountainMan.vx += this.mountainMan.accelerationX;
        this.viking.vx += this.viking.accelerationX;

        this.mountainMan.x -= this.mountainMan.vx;
        this.viking.x += this.viking.vx;            
    }
}
```

this method runs using recursion with `requestAnimationFrame`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were doing this to support Canvas and WebGL renderers....

For my mountainMan, it would be a class that contained 1 sprite with alpha 1, and then behind it maybe a 2 or 3 more sprites with increasing transparency. Then, on each update, each transparent image sets itself to an offset position from the main sprite.

So if the main sprite was at position 100, with moving on the x axis to the right at a velocity of 30, I might make transparent sprite 1 at 90, transparent sprite 2 at 80, and transparent sprite 3 at 70. If he was moving at a velocity of 9, I'd move them to positions 97, 94 and 91. This way you get the trail effect where the faster you go the more spread out the ghost images are.